# Is it possible to add a tag to an image in google cloud container registry without installing docker locally?

Tags: google-container-registry

I need to add a tag on an image on a repo in Google Container Registry, and I was wondering whether this could be done without having to install docker locally and doing `pull`, `tag`, `push` on the image. I know how to do so using the UI, but I wanted to automate this process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a Google Container Registry specific solution, you can use the `gcloud container images add-tag` command. For example:

`gcloud container images add-tag gcr.io/myproject/myimage:mytag1 \
    gcr.io/myproject/myimage:mytag2`

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/add-tag

If you want to use code, I'd suggest taking a look at those libraries

- **Go**: https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry
- **Python**: https://github.com/google/containerregistry

Comment: There's also `crane cp <old-tag> <new-tag>`, which if both tags are in the same registry, is just a quick metadata operation and no layers are transferred. https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/master/cmd/crane/doc/crane_copy.md

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use Docker you have the option to use the gcloud command line, you need just to configured Docker to use [gcloud as a credential helper](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing):

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

After that you can List images by their storage location:

```
gcloud container images list --repository=[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]
```

Or List the versions of an image

```
gcloud container images list-tags [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]
```

And you can as well [Tag images](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/add-tag)

```
gcloud container images add-tag \
[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]:[TAG] \
[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]:[NEW_TAG]
```

or

```
gcloud container images add-tag \
[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]@[IMAGE_DIGEST] \
[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]:[NEW_TAG]
```

All the described above can be done trough the UI as well.

For your question "I wanted to automate this process" not sure what are you looking for but you can create a bash script including the gcloud command and run it from you cloud shell